# Hide that website has been made with Angular

Tags: angular, web, production

I was wondering if I could have an opportunity to hide that my simple website was made with Angular. I could see this `<app-root _nghost-iie-c28="" ng-version="11.0.4"><router-outlet _ngcontent-iie-c28="">` on the website and thought that all Angular Websites got these tags, but no. So, which way can I hide them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Related [ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16283#issuecomment-347800960)

Simply add in your root component for removing version attribute:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[data-app]',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._elementRef.nativeElement.removeAttribute("ng-version");
    }
}
```

When it comes to the `_nghost`attribute it seems you wont get away with it the way you setup your app since point to where to populate content, however you could create a new component and add routing there so it shows further down the tree if you don't want it in your root component.

**Note:** As mentioned in the ticket related discussions, this might be mostly for production build as some tools are dependent on the attribute for dev builds.